# Relationship without any physical contact is acceptable?

Tags: halal-haram, relationships

I'm a girl of 18 years and have been in a relationship with my cousin brother from past 1 and half year we haven't touched each other yet we just talk on the phone weekly, or after a long time, and have also decided not to get in any sought of physical contact until we get married.

Is halal or haram to be in this kind of relationship where we both don't want to get touched?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam stack exchange. Please consider to take our [tour] and check our [help] to learn more about this site.

Comment: And I would like to tell you one more thing we have decided not to get in any kind of physical touch until we get married then being with him in relationship is correct or should I leave him

Comment: I have edited my post so please have a look on it and advise me about this matter

Answer (score 2):

The Prophet PBUH said:

> "Allaah has decreed for the children of Adam a share in adultery, he will get it by all means, the adultery of eyes is looking; **the adultery of tongue is speaking;** the soul desires and has a passion; the private parts confirms or falsifies it." (Source: http://sunnah.com/abudawud/12/107)

Noticed that actions towards adultery are not limited to physical contact. In the hadits above, even speaking might lead you to adultery. So in your case, since you said that you and your cousin are limited to phone (i.e. speaking), then the things that make it halal or haram are the things you both said during your conversation. Will Allah approve them or not? If your conversation contains something that Allah dislikes, it might be haram. If you're really-really-really sure that Allah approves, it might be halal.

That being said, I'd still suggest that you refrain from prolonging your relationship with your cousin. Syaithan is clever and persistent. If syaithan managed to convince you to take "small and innocent steps" toward adultery, he might manage to convince you to go all the way. Thus, the best approach is to steer clear as Allah prescribed in Al Quran Surah Al Isra' verse 32:

> "And **do not approach** unlawful sexual intercourse. Indeed, it is ever an immorality and is evil as a way" (Source: http://quran.com/17/32)

Allah knows best.