# I want to stay with my boyfriend but I fear that it's haram to be in relationship

Tags: halal-haram, quran, nikah, sharia, sunnah

So my boyfriend and I have been in a long distance relationship for about 6 months and both of us are muslims and we made sure that we won't make any physical touch until we get married but the problem is that we're too young for marriage and we want to tell our parents about our relationship but as they are over protective they won't accept it and they will definitely force us to stop talking to each other.

We don't want to do anything out of Shari'a so I wanna know if we should stay together until we become old enough to marry each other or break up now. We don't want to make anything haram and we really love each other and we want to spend the rest of our lives together.

If we have to separate now then we'll do it and we're ready for that. I need your advices brothers.

edit: I forgot to mention a few things: we communicate through texting + we rarely call each other + we don't talk about sexual things + we never met

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33671/relationship-without-any-physical-contact-is-acceptable?rq=1

Comment: Salam and welcome to ISlamSE the Q&A site about Islam. You once say "I want to stay with my boyfriend but I fear that it's haram to be in relationship" and then say "We don't want to do anything out of Shari'a". Actually any interaction between you and a foreign person (a non-Mahram and a boyfriend is of this kind) in absence of a mahram that goes beyond necessary interaction such as answering a greeting, work or sales communication is haram.